# How do I merge two toolbars into one in Caja?

Tags: mate, caja

In Caja file manager, there are two toolbars, one for navigation and the other for entering the path. I would like to merge them into one, just like other file managers. Is there some configuration file to edit? I would like to remove some buttons and customize the toolbar as well so it could fit nicely on screen.

Comment: Sounds useful, but it seems there is no such option in Dconf or GSettings. You can ask on [Ubuntu-MATE community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/) to be completely sure.